# crazy spikes when adding wireframe modifier

Tags: wireframe

I'm working with this model:
https://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/1005602

Totally groovy, right?

So I am trying to add a wireframe modifier for use in some game experiments with LibGDX. However when I add the modifier for this particular model, I get these crazy spikes shooting all over the place. Actually is kind of freaky cool. But won't work so well for my purposes.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

[image: Before - object mode]
[image: After wireframe]
[image: After wireframe view2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html):

> Wireframe thickness is an approximation. While Even Thickness should
>   yield good results in many cases, skinny faces can cause ugly spikes.
>   In this case you can either reduce the extreme angles in the geometry
>   or disable the Even Thickness option.

In this case you have to uncheck the "even thickness" option:

[image]

Comment: Would be good to get a link to or even a partial quote of what it is the manual says. Would give a little more context as to why this works.

Comment: Check the orange warning in this page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html

Comment: omg you guys read manuals ?? Seriously though, it didn't happen with another simpler model which made me think something was messed up with this one. Thanks for the infos.